# Gift message field doesn't show up

Tags: magento2

Despite being enabled "Allow Gift Messages on Order Level", it doesn't show up in the edit cart page. Tried clearing cache, but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, make sure you save your config in the correct **Scope**.

Starting debugging, open your browser's Developer tool, and check the **Console** tab to see if there are any JS errors related to the Gift message.

And check the **Network** tab to check if it contains the gift message's templates and JS files loaded or not.
[image]

Comment: I find this JS error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return customer().fullname }"
Message: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: html: 'Perfect Makeup Mirrors is where you'll find the make up mirror that's perfect for you.'
Message: Unexpected identifier '

Comment: Scope is the `default Config` always for our store. You can visit our store at perfectmakeupmirrors.com

Comment: I've checked your site, JS error blocks the gift message HTML rendering. You have to fix JS error to show the gift message section.

Comment: The reason for the JS error is your Welcome Text has a problem with the single quotes **'**. You have to escape all single quotes by adding \ before the single quotes. Go to Admin menu > Content > Design > Configuration > Select your theme > Header > Welcome Text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Escaping quotes fixed the JS error that in return made the Gift options visible.

Comment: Sure, deleted all irrelevant comments. I found the cause of the issue which was related to the theme I was building.

Comment: Tu Van, here is the new question about the theme that Magento admin uses. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360608/magento-2-4-4-what-is-the-theme-that-magento-admin-uses