# Magento 2.4.4: What is the theme that Magento admin uses?

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, custom-theme, static-content-deploy

I recently made a change to my setup:static-content:deploy command as `php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Perfectmakeupmirrors/argento-luxury-custom`  to narrow down it to the specific theme. As a result of this, Magento admin constantly gave HTTP Error 500. When I removed `--theme Perfectmakeupmirrors/argento-luxury-custom` and reran the command, admin page worked fine leaving me to wonder what is the actual theme that Magento admin uses.

Could you please share your insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Magneto Admin use

```
Magento/Backend Theme.
```

Answer (score 2):

For admin panel Magento use below theme.

```
Magento/backend
```

For deploy only admin static content you can use below command.

```
bin/magento s:s:d -f --theme Magento/backend
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A new admin theme for the adobe changes called `magento/spectrum`

Comment: That is [true as of version 2.4.5](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/) however the question is about Magento 2.4.4